# In JDK 1.6, can String equals operation can be replaced with ==?

Tags: java, string, equals

As I study the source code of some open source products, I find code like:

```
if (a=="cluser")
```

`a` is a String variable. Can a String `equals` operation be replaced with `==`?

Comment: No, the `==` still means object reference equality. That code you're reading is incorrect if it's trying to do string comparison.

Comment: often 3rdparty code is based on Strings being interned, such as lucene or some xml parsers. If that is the case, then == is fine to use.

Comment: *"... I find code like ..."* - Yea.  There are bugs in a lot of products ... both open source and closed source.

Comment: Some of us like to show off what clever buggers we are and use == for Strings in cases where it is safe.  It's a character flaw, but what can you do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should almost **never** use `==` and almost **always** use `equals()`. It will only work with `==` if both strings reference the same object. There's an `intern()` method on `String` to return the same reference for a given string value. String literals are implicitly interned. Only if you have a very good reason should you use `==` for string comparison, and even then you need to be very careful.

The only good reason is performance, and very rarely will it matter. Only optimize once **you know for sure** that you need to do so. It's otherwise normally not worth the hassle. If you're looking at some open source code, they might have a case whereby the comparison is in a very tight loop or called very frequently and the optimization can help. Or it was just prematurely optimized and maybe seemed safe.

Answer (score 4):

You can use == if the two strings are interned.  String literals are defined to be interned, so if I, say, assign the literal "fred" to a String variable and pass it as a parameter to a method in another class where it's compared to "fred", the == test will be true.

So the specimen code is not certainly defective, just probably so.

Comment: *"just probably so"* - this cannot be emphasized too strongly!

Answer (score 3):

only if the strings have been 'interned'. Normally no.

Answer (score 1):

From the Java Language Specification, section 3.10.5 String Literals

Each string literal is a reference to an instance of class String. String objects have a constant value. String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

Thus, the test program consisting of the compilation unit:

```
package testPackage;
class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String hello = "Hello", lo = "lo";
                System.out.print((hello == "Hello") + " ");
                System.out.print((Other.hello == hello) + " ");
                System.out.print((other.Other.hello == hello) + " ");
                System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+"lo")) + " ");
                System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+lo)) + " ");
                System.out.println(hello == ("Hel"+lo).intern());
        }
}
class Other { static String hello = "Hello"; }
```

and the compilation unit:

```
package other;

public class Other { static String hello = "Hello"; }
```

produces the output:

```
true true true true false true
```

This example illustrates six points:

1. Literal strings within the same
   class in the same package represent
   references to the same String
   object.
2. Literal strings within different
   classes in the same package
   represent references to the same
   String object.
3. Literal strings within different
   classes in different packages
   likewise represent references to the
   same String object.
4. Strings computed by constant
   expressions are computed at compile
   time and then treated as if they
   were literals.
5. Strings computed by concatenation at
   run time are newly created and
   therefore distinct.
6. The result of explicitly interning a
   computed string is the same string
   as any pre-existing literal string
   with the same contents.

Answer (score 0):

The == operator checks to see if two objects are exactly the same object. It doesn't compare what's in the strings.