# Unexpected result, when comparing two Java-Strings with "=="

Tags: java, string, compare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference Between Equals and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and)
>   [In JDK 1.6, can String equals operation can be replaced with ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839196/in-jdk-1-6-can-string-equals-operation-can-be-replaced-with)
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

While playing around with Java-Strings, i did not expect the following results:

```
public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "hello";
        String b = "hello";

        System.out.println(a == b);             //true        Why?, a and b both are seperate Objects
        System.out.println(a == "hello");       //true        Why?
        System.out.println(a == new String(b)); //false       As expected
    }
}
```

I expected all to be false, since "==" compares references. Why this outcome?

When i change `String b = "world"`, `System.out.println(a == b);` returns  `false`. It seems as if the content of the String-Object is beeing compared.

Since Java 7 can compare Strings in switch-case-Statements, i thought it might have something to to with the Java-Version. But as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), the equals-Methode is invoked when comparing Strings within a Switch-Case.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971954/difference-between-equals-and).

Comment: In summary, some strings are interned (i.e. cached) and refer to the same object, which explains why == can work. But you can't rely on that mechanism and should use equals.

Comment: Bottom line is, as string is still and object, so in the vast majority of cases you should be using the `equals` method.

Answer (score 3):

Java has always (from version 1.0) interned string literals. This means that constant strings are added to a pool and duplicates reference the same object.

```
final String a = "hello";
final String b = "hell";
System.out.println(a == b + 'o');
```

This prints `true` as the compiler can inline and simplify the expression `b + 'o'` to be the same as "hello".

Answer (score 2):

The JVM performs [some trickery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) while instantiating string literals to increase performance and decrease memory overhead. To cut down the number of String objects created in the JVM, the String class keeps a pool of strings. Each time your code create a string literal, the JVM checks the string literal pool first. If the string already exists in the pool, a reference to the pooled instance returns. If the string does not exist in the pool, a new String object instantiates, then is placed in the pool. Java can make this optimization since strings are immutable and can be shared without fear of data corruption.

Comment: It's called *string interning* and is common in most modern languages - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: Yes, it was already explained in other comments. _Some trickery_ could have been to vague.